# Remove steam and its dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, steam

Some time ago I installed Steam by downloading the deb file from their website. There were a lot of unmet dependencies which got solved by `sudo apt-get -f install`. When I tried to remove steam, using `sudo apt-get remove steam-launcher`, it seems to have removed only that package and not the n number of unmet dependencies that it showed at the time of installation.
Is there any way of checking whether those unnecessary packages are removed or not? And if those are still present, how do I remove?
Edit: `sudo apt autoremove` doesn't list any packages to be removed.

Comment: It may sound counter-intuitive, but have you tried running `sudo apt-get install steam-launcher` to overwrite the files as apt-installed, therefore `sudo apt-get remove steam-launcher && apt autoremove` may work.

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice There is no steam-launcher package for xenial, but there is just `steam`. Trying to install it gives error `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/steam_1%3a1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 30
Installation terminated: Steam License Agreement was DECLINED.` It never asked for agreement!

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`, it would seem that Steam is stuck in an install loop

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

However, check what kind of packages it will offer to remove before pressing enter, as it may offer to remove some packages that you still use.

Comment: It doesn't list any packages to be removed. As far as I know `autoremove` only removes any unnecessary dependencies that were installed by apt by default.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment suggested, you could try re-installing steam via

```
apt-get install steam
```

Which would mark the files as "installed by apt," therefore making it more possible to remove these files via other aptitude commands (`apt autoremove`, `apt-get remove`, etc)

If that doesn't work, you can always go with a more hands-on approach. Open up terminal and run

```
find . -name "steam"
```

And any files that were installed under steam, or the steam launcher should be in the path(s) found by the command.